# Homebuyer Credit - 2008 Installment Repayment

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate

I bought my house in 2008. I took the $7,500 credit. I remembered that I have payed $500 each year in 1040.

Now I have to fill the tax form this year. How to fill the two textboxs.

[image: tax form]

Comment: Good question Love!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my friends at [IRS.gov](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Tax-Credit-to-Aid-First-Time-Homebuyers;-Must-Be-Repaid-Over-15-Years):

> The credit operates much like an interest-free loan, because it must
>   be repaid over a 15-year period. So, for example, an eligible taxpayer
>   who buys a home today and properly claims the maximum available credit
>   of $7,500 on his or her 2008 federal income tax return must begin
>   repaying the credit by including one-fifteenth of this amount, or
>   $500, as an additional tax on his or her 2010 return.

So, $7500 in first field, and you 'should' have paid $500 in 2010 and 2011, or $1000 total in second field.

Comment: So the second field is 4*$500 =2000, which includes year 2008, 2009, 2010 and 2011?

Comment: Read the IRS doc I linked to. It says that if you took the credit in 2008, you started to pay it back in 2010. So 2010 + 2011 = $1000 in second field

Comment: Thank you very much. The above plan is based on the joint filing. If I want to separate filing, should I divide it between me and my wife?